# TupleCodec Error: Invalid tuple type, expected Tuple(TEXT, TIMEUUID) but got Tuple(TEXT, UUID)

Tags: datastax-java-driver, cassandra-4.0

Here's my table

```
create table face_by_personid(
                             user_uid text,
                             person_id text,
                             file_id timeuuid,
                             face_id text,
                             face_details face_details,
                             modification_date timestamp,
                             global_modification_date timestamp static,
                             primary key((user_uid), person_id, file_id, face_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (person_id ASC, file_id DESC)
```

My query

```
select face_id,person_id from face_by_personid where user_uid=:userUid and (person_id, file_id) in :tupleValues`;
```

My java code

```
BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind()
    .setString("userUid", userUid)
    .setList("tupleValues", tupleValues, TupleValue.class)`
```

Tuple Type

```
tupleTextUuid = DataTypes.tupleOf(DataTypes.TEXT,DataTypes.UUID) 

public TupleValue getTupleTextUuid(String string2, UUID uuid1) {
    return tupleTextUuid.newValue(string2,uuid1);
}
```

Using datastax driver 4.

On execution I'm getting -> Invalid tuple type, expected Tuple(TEXT, TIMEUUID) but got Tuple(TEXT, UUID)

Registered codecs

```
codecRegistry.register(new TimeUuidCodec());
codecRegistry.register(new UuidCodec());`
```